# Querying based on date range by using month and year numbers in SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @startMonth int
DECLARE @endMonth int

DECLARE @startYear int
DECLARE @endYear int

SET @startMonth = 1
SET @endMonth =5

SET @startYear =2014
SET @endYear =2015

SELECT * FROM Table 
         WHERE (YEAR(Date)>=@startYear AND MONTH(Date) >= @startMonth)
              AND (YEAR(Date)<=@endYear AND MONTH(Date) <= @endMonth)
```

This is apparently returning results of any date between 2014-01-01 to 2014-05-31

and 2014-01-01 to 2015-05-31

but I would like to get any date from 2014-01-01 to 2015-05-31 instead.

How should I change the query? I should write the following?

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
         WHERE Date>=DATEFROMPARTS ( @startYear, @startMonth, 1 ) 
           AND Date <= DATEFROMPARTS ( @endYear, @endMonth, 31 ))
```

Then I end up with the problem that if the @endMonth does not contain 31 days. Then I would have to create another checking to ensure the correct number of end date.

I am sure there must be a better way of writing this. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: There are DATEFROMPARTS and EOMONTH functions in T-SQL

Comment: @DVT: in SQL Server **2012** and newer - yes - but if the OP is on 2008 or 2008 R2, he won't be able to use those ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(@startYear, @startMonth, 1)
  AND Date <  DATEFROMPARTS(@endYear, @endMonth + 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    <table_name>
WHERE
    date BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(@startYear,@startMonth,1) AND EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@endYear,@endMonth,1));
```

Comment: this function looks very cool but just supported in SQL server 2012.

Comment: btw knowing that datefrompart is also sql server 2012 function but I have a custom function in 2008 version which does the same job.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!